# USB C host and peripheral at the same time

Tags: usb-device, usb-c, usb-host

Can a Dual-Role USB C port (e.g. on a smartphone) be used in both roles at the same time?

So can it e.g. be connected to a PC and a keyboard at the same time?

Comment: It would be physically impossible to connect three ports together.

Comment: I wonder if usb 2 and usb 3 connections could be separated.

Comment: That said just use a Bluetooth keyboard. Tap power of you really need it. With a regulator just incase the power lines go above 5V aka usb power delivery.

Comment: @Finbarr: I am not talking about jamming two connectors in one socket. But it is totally possible to connect two devices to a host using a hub in between. The question was whether the USB protocol allows a dual-role device to do both roles at the same time using a hub or some other component.

Answer (score 3):

As I see it there's at least the possibility for some kind of dock to provide an upstream facing port for a PC and a downstream facing port for a keyboard and other devices.  Getting this to work depends plenty on the hardware and software in the phone that one plans to act in both roles.

In theory on a USB-C port with USB 2.0 and USB 3.x data paths the two paths can switch roles independently.  A dock could split the two USB data paths apart, and power too, so that it can offer a USB 2.0 path to a keyboard, USB 3.x path to a PC, and negotiate power from a USB-PD power supply.

If the phone is capable of Thunderbolt on USB-C then the solution is trivial, Thunderbolt is just PCIe by a different form factor so just add whatever interfaces are required.  The dock for the phone could have a PCIe USB controller for the keyboard, another PCIe USB controller for communication with the PC, and as many other PCIe controllers for whatever function is desired.  The communication to the PC doesn't have to be by USB, it could be by some other protocol.  The dock could contain a USB to Ethernet chip for the PC and an Ethernet adapter for the phone.

There's other methods to consider but in all cases there would have to be a dock of some sort to provide the right kind of ports, and enough electronics to direct the communications.  The phone might also need some extra software for this unusual setup.

The difficulty in doing this depends on the capability of the phone, and the capability of the person attempting this.  If the phone supports Thunderbolt then the solution could be as simple as finding the right Thunderbolt dock.  That's simple, just not cheap.  If the dock does not exist then a Thunderbolt PCIe breakout box and a careful selection of PCIe cards should do, and that's going to cost even more.

Some phones with USB-C support only USB 2.0 communications, and even in that case something could possibly be made to work.  One example is to plug in a USB hub, and off that hub plug in a keyboard and Ethernet adapter.  It's not going to look like a USB device to the PC but it will offer a communications path.

For the phone to communicate in both USB master and USB slave modes simultaneously will almost definitely require changes to the operating system.  This may even be true for the case of a phone with Thunderbolt support because the OS may not expect to see an upstream facing port where this new USB controller would be.

I see it as as possible, just not likely to be cheap or easy.

Answer (score 1):

No, wiring two ports together (in a 'splitter' configuration) would also require tying the data lines together which would significantly alter their impedance properties. If you need to split USBC, you'll need a hub chip in a design.

Comment: There is an off the shelf hub ic that allows dual host and peripheral at the same time?

Comment: USB C can go host to host if the controller chips support OTG.

Comment: I don't think a splitter configuration would help, since then I could only split data off power, but I need data on both ends. The question is just if a Dual Role device can at all do both roles at the same time.